# Where are the "managed project source files"?

Tags: visual-studio, vsx

Trying to follow this tutorial

[Walkthrough: Part 1 - Creating a Basic Project System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512961%28VS.100%29.aspx)

And I got to this step:

> Locate the managed project source files by following [this link](http://www.codeplex.com/mpfproj10/). Copy these files to a local folder named, for example, C:\MyLocalFolder\Project

But that codeplex project doesn't have any downloads... so what files am I supposed to copy?

Comment: Have you contacted the Admins of the project?

Comment: @Preet: No... I thought I might be missing something. Do they come with Visual Studio 2010 SDK perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft employee that worked on that got hit by a bus.  That happens, the traffic congestion in Redmond is epic.  It didn't progress to an official downloadable release version, you have to hump the check-ins.  Following the links takes me to [this page](http://mpfproj10.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets), the download link at the upper right corner is active for that one.  Looks complete, didn't try it.

Comment: Really? That's awful... thanks tho. I found this at about the same time you did.

Answer (score 0):

Oops... I've I read the page in its entirety, I would have noticed I was supposed to get it from the [Source Code](http://mpfproj10.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) tab.